# push notification azure to FCM topics

Tags: json, azure, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-chrome-app, azure-notificationhub

I want to push  notification messages from azure notification hub to the FCM using topics.

Example: I want to send a message to the FCM from notification hub. but this message will be directed to topics. When using postman for example, I just have to send this json:

```
{
    "to" : "/topics/scalability",
    "notification":{"body":"topics message sent"}
}
```

to  https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send (while providing the FCM key ofcourse).

By doing this, I am able to receive the notification on a chrome app I put in place (the app is just the same as you can find [here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/tree/master/messaging)

Now my problem is that when I send this same message on Notification hub (Azure), I don't receive it on my web app. My understanding is that the Notification Hub does not push the message (json) in its simple format, but why is that ?

Since I successfully pushed the message to FCM, isn't the FCM supposed to interpret the 
`"to" : "/topics/scalability`
 part ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a workaround. I send notifications using the simple version of the Notification hub method:

```
// Send the message to FCM NotificationOutcome outCome = await this.hubClient.SendGcmNativeNotificationAsync(payload).
```

I then receive all the messages from my chrome app

Answer (score 0):

Azure Notification Hub supports registering tags with individual device. And you can use tag expressions to target specific sets of devices, or more specifically registrations, when sending a push notification through Notification Hubs. For targeting, you should use tag expression instead FCM ‘to’ property. Please see below article for more details on routing/expressions.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-tags-segment-push-message

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of the tags. However, my purpose is to send message for all FCM token that are subscribed to a given topic. This said, i found a workaround. I send notifications using the simple version of the Notification hub method:   // Send the message to FCM
                NotificationOutcome outCome = await this.hubClient.SendGcmNativeNotificationAsync(payload). I then receive all the messages from my chrome app.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I also was confused by this when starting my first Topics-based notification hub app, so hope this saves someone, somewhere some time. What SHOULD, in my opinion, be explicitly stated somewhere in the azure NH documentation, is that using the hub with PNS such as Firebase will OVERRIDE any PNS specific Topics functionality. My understanding is that if you decide to go the Hub route, you ditch Firebase Topics etc and work exclusively with Hub Tags.

If you think about it, it actually makes a lot of sense as it means the Hub is dealing with Topic filtering rather than firing off all messages and making the PNS systems do their individual things.

So in short, if you go the NH route, you cant use PNS topics, I found the two don't play nicely together.